# How to list only unique couples from an XML using XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my XML structure:

```
<dblp>

<inproceedings key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
<author>author1</author>
<author>author2</author>
<author>author3</author>
<title>Title of pubblications</title>
<pages>12345</pages>
<year>12345</year>
<crossref>sometext</crossref>
<booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
<url>sometext</url>
<ee>sometext</ee>
</inproceedings>

<article key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
<author>author1</author>
<author>author4</author>
<title>Title of pubblications</title>
<pages>12345</pages>
<year>12345</year>
<crossref>sometext</crossref>
<booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
<url>sometext</url>
<ee>sometext</ee>
</article>

<article key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
<author>author1</author>
<author>author2</author>
<title>Title of pubblications</title>
<pages>12345</pages>
<year>12345</year>
<crossref>sometext</crossref>
<booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
<url>sometext</url>
<ee>sometext</ee>
</article>

<inproceedings key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
<author>author2</author>
<author>author1</author>
<author>author5</author>
<title>Title of pubblications</title>
<pages>12345</pages>
<year>12345</year>
<crossref>sometext</crossref>
<booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
<url>sometext</url>
<ee>sometext</ee>
</inproceedings>

</dblp>
```

I need to display all couples of authors who have collaborated for an article (and inproceedings).

So we need to list only unique couples, to know wich authors have collaborated.
This is my XSL where I list all couples, but i need to add some code to filter the selection and remove the couples already listed:

```
<xsl:variable name="papers" select="dblp/*"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$papers">
            <xsl:for-each select="author[position() != last()]">
                <xsl:variable name="a1" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::author">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(translate(translate($a1,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), '--', translate(translate(translate(.,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), ';&#10;')"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Current output:

```
author1--auhtor2
author1--auhtor3
author2--auhtor3
author1--auhtor4
author1--auhtor2
author2--auhtor1
author2--auhtor5
author1--auhtor5
```

The output should be like this:

```
author1--auhtor2
author1--auhtor3
author2--auhtor3
author1--auhtor4
---
---
author2--auhtor5
author1--auhtor5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT 2.0 solution :

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/author" group-by=".">
    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="firstKey" select="current-grouping-key()"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/*/author[compare(.,  current-grouping-key()) = 1][some $x in (current-group()) satisfies $x/parent::* intersect ./parent::*]" group-by=".">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($firstKey, '--',current-grouping-key(),';&#10;')"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:for-each-group>    
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks all. I am not very expert in XSLT 2.0, but I see that significantly improves the life.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xslt element xsl:for-each-group or the function distinct-values() for this.

In the template below I have put your sequence generator in a variable called round1 so it can be processed to remove duplicates.  I have changed the inner loop to create an element (collab) with attributes pair (that matches your pairing) and an ordered version called cannonicalPair.  To the cannonicalPair is used to eliminate duplicates do to different order of the authors.  Note that sometimes the order of a collaboration is significant in the real world.

Following the round1 variable are a series of loops that remove the duplicates.  The first two show that you can output either ordering of the collaboration in your data set.  The last does not treat collaborations as duplicate if they have different order.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="papers" select="dblp/*"/> 
<xsl:variable name="round1">
        <xsl:for-each select="$papers"> 
            <xsl:for-each select="author[position() != last()]"> 
                <xsl:variable name="a1" select="."/> 
                <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::author"> 
                    <xsl:element name="collab">
                      <xsl:attribute name="pair"  select="concat(translate(translate(translate($a1,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), '--', translate(translate(translate(.,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), ';&#10;')"/> 
                      <xsl:attribute name="cannonicalPair">
                        <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="$a1 lt ." >
                            <xsl:sequence select="concat(translate(translate(translate($a1,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), '--', translate(translate(translate(.,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), ';&#10;')" />
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:sequence select="concat(translate(translate(translate(.,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), '--', translate(translate(translate($a1,' ','_'),'.',''),&quot;'&quot;,' '), ';&#10;')" />
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:attribute>  
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each-group select="$round1/collab" group-by="@cannonicalPair">
  <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/@pair" />
</xsl:for-each-group>

<xsl:text>---- listing seperator ----&#x0A;</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each-group select="$round1/collab" group-by="@cannonicalPair">
  <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/@pair" />
</xsl:for-each-group>

<xsl:text>---- listing seperator ----&#x0A;</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($round1/collab/@cannonicalPair)">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:text>---- listing seperator ----&#x0A;</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($round1/collab/@pair)">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks all. I am not very expert in XSLT 2.0, but I see that significantly improves the life

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation: complete, short and well-formatted** (27 lines):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="kAuthorBySibling" match="author"
     use="preceding-sibling::author | following-sibling::author"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vAuthors" as="element()*">
      <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/*/*/author)">
       <xsl:sort/>
       <a><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select=
      "for $a1 in $vAuthors,
         $doc in /,
           $a2 in $vAuthors
                   [. gt $a1
                  and
                    . = key('kAuthorBySibling', $a1, $doc)
                   ]

        return ($a1/string(), $a2/string(), '&#xA;')
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<dblp>
    <inproceedings key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
        <author>author1</author>
        <author>author2</author>
        <author>author3</author>
        <title>Title of pubblications</title>
        <pages>12345</pages>
        <year>12345</year>
        <crossref>sometext</crossref>
        <booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
        <url>sometext</url>
        <ee>sometext</ee>
    </inproceedings>
    <article key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
        <author>author1</author>
        <author>author4</author>
        <title>Title of pubblications</title>
        <pages>12345</pages>
        <year>12345</year>
        <crossref>sometext</crossref>
        <booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
        <url>sometext</url>
        <ee>sometext</ee>
    </article>
    <article key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
        <author>author1</author>
        <author>author2</author>
        <title>Title of pubblications</title>
        <pages>12345</pages>
        <year>12345</year>
        <crossref>sometext</crossref>
        <booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
        <url>sometext</url>
        <ee>sometext</ee>
    </article>
    <inproceedings key="aaa" mdate="bbb">
        <author>author2</author>
        <author>author1</author>
        <author>author5</author>
        <title>Title of pubblications</title>
        <pages>12345</pages>
        <year>12345</year>
        <crossref>sometext</crossref>
        <booktitle>sometext</booktitle>
        <url>sometext</url>
        <ee>sometext</ee>
    </inproceedings>
</dblp>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
 author1 author2
 author1 author3 
 author1 author4 
 author1 author5 
 author2 author3 
 author2 author5
```

**Explanation**:

1. The variable `$vAuthors` is a sequence of `a` elements whose set of string values is the set of distinct values of the `author` elements in the XML document. The `a` elements are sorted in this sequence.
2. The key `'kAuthorBySibling'` identifies any `author element by (the string value of) any of its siblings.
3. For each `$a1` in `$vAuthors` we get any `$a2` in `$vAuthors` with string value greater than that of `$a1` and such that an `author` element with string value equal to that of `$a2` is a sibling of an `author` element with string value equal to that of `$a1`. For this we simply check (using the general equality operator) whether the string value of `$a2` is in the set of string values of `key('kAuthorBySibling', $a1, $doc)`.